# MySQL Join 2 columns from table y into rows of table x

Tags: mysql, join, unpivot

Trying to wrap my mind around how to write this SQL query.

Table X has 3 Columns: `Year`, `ID`, `Value` and looks like so

```
Year   |   ID   |     Value
2013       101        10000
2014       101        11000
2015       101        12000
2013       102        7000
2014       102        8000
2015       102        9000
```

And table Y has 3 Columns: `ID`, `Curr_Year_Val`, `Next_Year_Val` and looks like this

```
ID   |  Curr_Year_Val   | Next_Year_Val
101        13000                  14000
102        6000                   5000
```

I would like to write a select statement to join these two tables together, but maintain the layout of Table X, like so:

```
Year           |    ID    |    Value
2013               101         10000
2014               101         11000
2015               101         12000
Curr_Year_Val      101         13000
Next_Year_Val      101         14000
```

Is there a way to achieve this result? I've figured out how to just do a left join to add the columns from table y to table x, but would rather have the columns from table y unpivoted to the rows of table x. Thanks much in advance - this seems like it should be so easy, I've been googling for hours but I'm probably not using the proper terminology for what I'm trying to do in my searches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should use `union all`:

```
select year, id, value from x
union all
select 'curr_year_val', id, curr_year_val from y
union all
select 'next_year_val', id, next_year_val from y
order by 2, 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d27fb/2)

BTW, other databases would require you to have the same data types for all columns when using `union`.  This works though with `mysql`.

Comment: Thank you! I was making it way more complicated in my head than it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Uee union

```
 select  year, id, value 
 from tableX
 where id ='101'
 union 
 select 'curr_year_val', id, curr_year_val 
 from tableY
 where id ='101'
 union 
 select 'next_year_val', id, next_year_val 
 from tableY 
 where id ='101'
```